# How can I deserialize the json response of azure devOps?

Tags: c#, json, azure-devops, null, deserialization

I am reffering my question to the  [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). I requested the azure devOps api to retrieve all repos hosted in a particular organization and project. The response is a json looking like following:

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "5febef5a-833d-4e14-b9c0-14cb638f91e6",
      "name": "AnotherRepository",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/5febef5a-833d-4e14-b9c0-14cb638f91e6",
      "project": {
        "id": "6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c",
        "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/projects/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c",
        "state": "wellFormed"
      },
      "remoteUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_git/AnotherRepository"
    },
    {
      "id": "278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249",
      "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249",
      "project": {
        "id": "6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c",
        "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/projects/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c",
        "state": "wellFormed"
      },
      "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/master",
      "remoteUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git"
    },
    {
      "id": "66efb083-777a-4cac-a350-a24b046be6be",
      "name": "TestGit",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/66efb083-777a-4cac-a350-a24b046be6be",
      "project": {
        "id": "281f9a5b-af0d-49b4-a1df-fe6f5e5f84d0",
        "name": "TestGit",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/projects/281f9a5b-af0d-49b4-a1df-fe6f5e5f84d0",
        "state": "wellFormed"
      },
      "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/master",
      "remoteUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_git/TestGit"
    }
  ]
}
```

The [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) says that the api returns type `GitRepository[]` so I want to deserialize the json into that type but how can I do that??

Because of the `count` and `value` property I built a HelperClass like following:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public GitRepository[] value { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}
```

But after the deserialization and cast into that object all the props of `GitRepository` are null.

Can someone help me why all the properties are null??

EDIT: This is the deserialization

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string accessToken = "personal_access_token";
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", string.Empty, accessToken))));

            var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1");
            var responseObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(response);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where the actual deserialization happens?

Comment: @rytisk Yes I added an edit containing the deserialization code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you doing your deserialization? Where have you defined the `GitRepository` class? Have you tried deserializing into string to check if any members have changed? The documentation is from 2016, and might have changed since.

You could instead use the nuget packages provided by Microsoft to access these APIs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops

I think the NuGet package you need is [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/)

Comment: Yes indeed the ```GitRepository``` Class is part of the mentioned NuGet package so its not defined by myself

Comment: Then you can use the client provided in the NuGet and not deserialize it yourself

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` is by default case-sensitive. `GitRepository` property names are PascalCase while your provided json example contains CamelCase names. So JsonSerializer can't deserialize those properties correctly.

You can override the default settings by providing `JsonSerializerOptions`:

```
var responseObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(response, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
});
```

Also I noticed that `project` property is still not being deserialized. I guess it's because `GitRepository` has a property called `ProjectReference` (instead of `Project`) and has a DataMember attribute.

It looks like `System.Text.Json` doesn't respect the DataMember attribute. So I suggest you use `Newtonsoft.Json` library. I tested it and it works fine:

```
var responseObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise I found a solution with the TFS client!:-)